# probability mass function of number of cards required until a club

Tags: probability

> Cards are drawn sequentially from a standard deck of $52$ cards until a club appears. Let X denote the number of cards required. Find the probability mass function of X.

My solution:

P(X=k)= $\frac{\binom{39}{k-1}}{\binom{52}{k-1}}$ * $\frac{13}{\binom{52-k-1}{1}}$

Is this correct?

Edit: Answer given in solutions is
$\frac{\binom{39}{k-1}}{\binom{52}{k-1}}$ * $\frac{13}{\binom{53-k}{1}}$ where $k \in\ {1,\dots\ ,40}$.
Hence the confusion.

Comment: The book answer is correct, check for a simple example, e.g. for k = 2. Obviously, the answer should be $\frac{\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}} \frac{\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{51}{1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but don't forget to indicate the support.
$$\mathsf P(X=k) = \dfrac{\binom{39}{k-1}\cdot 13}{\binom{52}{k-1}\cdot(51-k)}[k\in\{1,\dots,40\}]$$

Comment: But $\frac{\binom{39}{k-1}}{\binom{52}{k-1}}$ * $\frac{13}{\binom{53-k}{1}}$  
where  $[k \in\ 1,\dots\,40]$
This is the answer given in solutions book!!!